# How to implement search in a graphics layer?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

There is a method that accepts JSON data. Based on this data, points are created and added to the graphics layer. How to implement search in a graphics layer? I found an example of how to implement search in FeatureLayer ([sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=widgets-search-multiplesource))! How to do the same in GraphicsLayer?

**A method that draws the JSON points:**

```
function draw_point_layer(stations, list_name_net) {
                console.log(stations);
                for (i = 0; i < stations.length; i++) {
                    var point = {
                        type: "point", // autocasts as new Point()
                        longitude: stations[i]['longitude'],
                        latitude: stations[i]['latitude']
                    };
                    var pointAtt = {
                        Code: stations[i]['sitecode'],
                        Name: "<a href='" + stations[i]['link'] + "'>" + stations[i]['name'] + "</a>",
                        Type: stations[i]['type'],
                        Nets: list_name_net[i]
                    };
                    var pointGraphic = new Graphic({
                        geometry: point,
                        symbol: markerSymbol,
                        attributes: pointAtt,
                        popupTemplate: {
                            content: [{
                                type: "fields",
                                fieldInfos: [
                                    {
                                        fieldName: "Code",
                                        label: 'Код',
                                    },
                                    {
                                        fieldName: "Name",
                                        label: 'Имя',
                                    },
                                    {
                                        fieldName: "Type",
                                        label: 'Тип',
                                    },
                                    {
                                        fieldName: "Nets",
                                        label: 'Сети',
                                    },
                                ]
                            }]
                        }
                    });
                    pointLayer.add(pointGraphic);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [search documentation](http://Feature%20layers%20created%20from%20client-side%20graphics%20are%20not%20supported.):
"The Search widget provides a way to perform search operations on locator service(s) and/or map/feature service feature layer(s)"
"Feature layers created from client-side graphics are not supported."
Based on the doc, it seems that the Search widget can't be used for graphics layers.